# Stop click from fading an image when visable

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

This is prabobly basic jQuery stuff but I can't seem to find the right code that fits my needs.

So, im trying to set up this simple image fader. If a button is clicked, one image fades into the other. The problem is that I want to stop this event from happening when the image is already visible. 
The way i have set this up now makes the image fadeOut, then FadeIn even though it's already faded in. This way I can keep clicking the button multiple times.

Is there I way i can stop this from happening? 
If visible then unbind click?

Any smarter people out there? Thanks in advance!

```
$('#services .serviceWrap h3').click(function (event) {

    var Service = 'service' + $(this).attr("id");

    $('#services .serviceWrap img').fadeToggle(200, function () {
        $('#services .serviceWrap img').attr("src", 'img/' + Service + '.gif');
        $('#services .serviceWrap img').fadeToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `click event` add  a `condition` like

```
if($('#services .serviceWrap img').is(':visible')){
     //do something
}else{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: This will totally work, thanks for your answer. Only problem is, what to put in "do something"? :P

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not the answer to the question. We can do something with an If / else event, the question is what?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just check if is it visible? `$(".someElement").is(":visible")`?
Or isn't that what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, i fixed this with adding a class (active) to the button and using simple css to disable the click:

```
.active {
pointer-events:none;
cursor: default
}
```

Comment: What a counter intuitive way to solve that.
It's not exactly clear in what it does, and its badly supported in earlier browsers.
http://caniuse.com/pointer-events